# Regular Expression for Microsoft Dynamics 2016 address field

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am trying to use a Regular Expression to stop applicants that do not use proper capitalization in this application.

I only want the first letter of each word to be capitalized, for example "25 Front Street". If someone enters "25 front Street", I would like the Regular Expression Validation Error to become visible until corrections are made.

I've tried a few different ways and can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Can you post what you tried? How does it differ from the expected behaviour?

Comment: function toTitleCase(str){return str.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});}

Comment: It stops and shows the message but when I correct the capitalization it still stops me from continuing

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the first letter of each word to be capitalized: whether that letter is followed by digits or alphabets.

RegExp to match a capitalized word exactly: `/\b([A-Z](?:[A-Za-z])*)/g`.

RegExp to find all the words in a string: `/\b(?:[A-Za-z]+)/g`.

Using a combination of both I have created a validator for you to test here: https://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/zp6drbma/32/

Hope this satisfies your requirements.

Also, here is the regex tester I created to test various strings: https://regex101.com/r/jHfOU8/5

Comment: Thank you, I put this in the tester and an error comes up, it says / An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)

Comment: In the regex tester it is assumed that /.../g will be added by default. Only paste this much code: `\b([A-Z](?:[A-Za-z])*)`

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but I don't want to change the letters to capital, etc. I just want the error message to stay until the address is fixed.

Comment: That worked! I'm going to put it in my Test and see the results. You are the BEST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I put in in my Test application but it is still not working, the message does not disappear when the corrections are made.

Comment: It's not working in my application, the message stays and correct the capitalization does nothing to it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is how you are removing the error message. Please give me your application code where you are removing the error message on correcting the string.

Comment: I don't know how to paste in here? In the Extended Field Properties of my application I have:

Comment: Optional Regular Expression Validation is your script

Comment: Regular Expression Validation Error is <font color="#ff0000"></p>Please use correct capitalization</font>

Comment: Explanatory Text and Additional CSS Classes are both blank

Comment: Is the corrected string you are giving to the application working in the regex tester?

Comment: It is working in the tester, but it seems I need to shut it off when it's corrected. The Regular Expression Validation Error is <font color="#ff0000></p>Please use correct capitalization</font>

Comment: So the Regex is fine. But there maybe some problem in the way Microsoft Dynamics works with Validations.